# SpreadsheetReader - getting int data from row php

Tags: php, arrays, excel

I'm trying to get data from a file *.xls. Everything is going well for the moment of display the data.

*.php code:

```
$Spreadsheet = new SpreadsheetReader("test.xls");

$Sheets = $Spreadsheet -> Sheets();

foreach ($Sheets as $Index => $Name)
{
    $Spreadsheet -> ChangeSheet($Index);

    foreach ($Spreadsheet as $Key => $Row)
    {
        print_r($Row);
    }
}
```

Display result:

```
Array (
[0] => Col1
[1] => Col2
[2] => Col3
) Array (
[0] => General
[1] => General
[2] => One123two
) Array (
[0] => General
[1] => like
[2] => General
)
```

Instead of string 'General', the numbers should appear (and that's how my excel/calc file looks like):

```
Array (
[0] => Col1
[1] => Col2
[2] => Col3
) Array (
[0] => 123
[1] => 123
[2] => One123two
) Array (
[0] => 412
[1] => like
[2] => 1517
)
```

[test.xls File](https://i.stack.imgur.com/78lfX.png)

I also try to change the extension to test.ods, and everything is perfectly fine but my main target file getting me a error message:

```
> Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'Exception' with message 'SpreadsheetReader_ODS: File not readable (File 2.ods) (Error 19)' in /libs/excelreader/SpreadsheetReader_ODS.php:65 Stack trace: #0 /libs/excelreader/SpreadsheetReader.php(177): SpreadsheetReader_ODS->__construct('File 2.ods', Array) #1 /import-customers.php(36): SpreadsheetReader->__construct('File 2.ods') #2 {main} thrown in /libs/excelreader/SpreadsheetReader_ODS.php on line 65
```

I'm getting that error when dealing with *.ods file which is about 3,6mb big with 48 columns and 10k rows. When trying to change that file to *.xls I get the same result as with test.xls file, that is, in every cell instead of integer (number) I get a "General" word.

But to be honest, I've no idea that's that error means.

Comment: please provide at least some line of the xls

Answer (score 0):

Partially solved.

The main file *.ods was damaged. It turned out that the file was corrupted. It weighed too much (rather than 3.6MB should be 1MB) but after opening corrupted file it looked all right.

The solution was to save again the original file using "save as". After that the file has been successfully read by script. However, in the part where it was used * .xls file, still, instead of numbers appears the word "General".